# Flow Failing On Create Of Lead

Tags: visual-workflow

I m trying to create a lead record from a flow. It is failing with the following error.

> This error occurred when the flow tried to update records:
> REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Required fields are missing: [Company]

However I am setting the Company to a string. So what is wrong here?

Comment: In order to see what's wrong, please present the relevant sections of your Flow, e.g. with screenshots.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're mapping to a string if the string is blank.